# Difference between pd.concat() and pd.merge() and why do I get wrong output?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, merge, concatenation

I am facing a difficulty with two dataframes I need to join. I usually apply pd.merge(). but in this case I get a ValueError and I am recommended to use pd.concat(). So, my case is this:

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2 and these are their indices below.

```
In [15]: df1.index
Out[15]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-03 00:00:00', '2019-11-03 01:00:00',
               '2019-11-03 02:00:00', '2019-11-03 03:00:00',
               ...
               '2019-11-12 11:00:00', '2019-11-12 12:00:00',
               '2019-11-12 13:00:00', '2019-11-12 14:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='datetime', length=231, freq=None)


In [16]: df2.index
Out[16]: 
Index(['2019-11-03 00:00:00', '2019-11-04 00:00:00',
       '2019-11-05 00:00:00', '2019-11-06 00:00:00',
       '2019-11-07 00:00:00', '2019-11-08 00:00:00',
       '2019-11-09 00:00:00', '2019-11-10 00:00:00',
       '2019-11-11 00:00:00', '2019-11-12 00:00:00'],
      dtype='object', name='datetime')
```

When I try to merge the two dataframes by `merged=pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['datetime'], right_on=['datetime'], how='left')` I get a message `ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

Allow me to give you an idea of the two dataframes too.

```
temperatures = [c for c in df1 if c.startswith('temp')]
df1['temp_mean']=df1[temperatures].mean(axis=1)

In [6]: df1.head(3)
Out[6]:
                    location  temperature1  temperature2  wind  rain  temp_mean
datetime                                           
2019-10-03 00:00:00       HK        18.72          18.78    SW   0.0      18.75
2019-10-03 01:00:00       HK        18.63          18.67    SW   0.1      18.65
2019-10-03 02:00:00       HK        18.29          18.31    SW   0.3      18.30

In [7]:df2
Out[7]: 
                       values
datetime                     
2019-11-03 00:00:00  0.154286
2019-11-04 00:00:00 -5.094286
2019-11-05 00:00:00  1.432857
2019-11-06 00:00:00  0.227143
2019-11-07 00:00:00  0.160000
2019-11-08 00:00:00  1.300000
2019-11-09 00:00:00  0.308571
2019-11-10 00:00:00  0.442857
2019-11-11 00:00:00  0.241429
2019-11-12 00:00:00       NaN
```

Apparently, by merging the two dataframes, I expected that column "values" of df2 will join df1 at the end and that any time != '00:00:00' would be filled in with NaN and that the values would be placed at time == '00:00:00'. Since I get the Error and suggestion to use pd.concat(), I type `concated=pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='outer', ignore_index=False)` and I get the output below where the column "values" is there but totally empty (at all times I get NaNs).

```
In [17]: concated.head(3)
Out[17]:
                    location  temperature1  temperature2  wind  rain  temp_mean  \
datetime                                           
2019-10-03 00:00:00       HK        18.72          18.78    SW   0.0      18.75
2019-10-03 01:00:00       HK        18.63          18.67    SW   0.1      18.65
2019-10-03 02:00:00       HK        18.29          18.31    SW   0.3      18.30

                      values
datetime                                           
2019-10-03 00:00:00      NaN
2019-10-03 01:00:00      NaN
2019-10-03 02:00:00      NaN
```

I do not understand what I do wrong here and how I can make this work.

At the very beginning, I do not understand why `pd.merge()` does not work with my dataframes and then I do not get why `pd.concat()` does not see the values.

Your help will be valuable at this point, so thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with `left_index=True` and  `right_index=True` because match by `DatetimeIndex` in both `DataFrame`s:

```
#convert to DatetimeIndex
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: well... YES! it worked. Thank you so much! So, when the datetime are indices there are specific arguments I must apply in the method.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to merge on datetime columns which have different datatypes.

df1 : dtype='datetime64[ns]'

df2 : dtype='object'

Solution: Convert either of the datatypes to other using, 
.dt.strftime (to convert to string)
or 
pd.to_datetime (to convert to datetime datatype)